# Blackberry 10 Native - How to detect network events

Tags: blackberry-10

How can I monitor the network connection status on Blackberry 10 platform using C++ code?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "network connection status"? Available transport types? Mobile reception? WiFi signal?

Comment: I want to know about the availability of Internet connection on the device.